# Internals of cordova build android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I looked all over the internet but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. 
I wanted to know the exact build process that `cordova` uses to build an `.apk`
file.

What is the internal process?

How does it deal with the *plugin*? Does it copy the *plugin* (js) or does it build the plugin *.java* file as well and packages into the .apk? 
The reason I'm also asking this question is when I do make changes to the *.java* plugin file , the build process doesn't build it. (Any compile error is not caught)?

Please can anybody shed a light or point to a resources that clarifies it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use the development workflow with a plugin, in which case you should be using `--link` when you add the plugin to your project. Docs

Linking accomplishes the following:

- The entire plugin is symlinked into `/plugins`; however changes to your plugin's `www` or `plugin.xml` file will require an `plugin rm` and `add`.
- The native code *files* are symlinked (not the entire plugin directory) in the appropriate location in `platforms/`. Changes to your native code files in the plugin directory *or* the native IDE should be reflected automatically on next build. (This does not apply to your plugin's JavaScript; this file is copied and not symlinked — you must `plugin rm` and `add` to update this.)

If you do not link your plugins during development, the following applies:

- Plugin files are copied into `plugins/` on install
- JS & Native code is copied to the appropriate location in `platforms/` on install (or `platform add`)
- Changes to `platforms/` will be reflected in your next build, *but will not be reflected back to your original plugin*.
- Changes to your plugin will *not* be reflected in your next build without a `plugin rm` and `add`, because the native files aren't linked